# JavaFX - Service Task not always running

Tags: javafx-8

I have a slightly odd issue and unfortunately it's not one I can easily write a standalone class for. 
Within my application I have a TableView (on a tab) which is clickable. Clicking on a row in this TableView opens a new Tab with a data relating to the clicked row in a new TableView. 
The TableViews are bound to a custom class that extends ModifiableObservableListBase. This allows a Scrollbar to be used to request new data from the server based on the top and bottom rows of the viewport.
This all works well.
I also have a Service in my subclass of ModifiableObservableListBase that is used to improve the rendering of data under high load. It uses a LinkedBlockingQueue and countDownLatch so that only most recent view is updated to the UI preventing unnecessary redraws. Using the following:

```
 setAll(list);
```

This also works well.

So far so good!

What I've noticed is that when I open and close these tabs multiple times (no fixed number), at some point the TableView will stop updating with data. The data is requested from the server and received but the Service which is used to control how data is added to the ModifiableObservableListBase fails to move out of the SCHEDULED state. This means that the Task that has been created never runs. I'm struggling to see why this would work correctly x times and then stop working. 
Any help would be really welcomed, sorry I don't have a standaone application that replicates this issue. I will try to recreate it.

The following Service is constructed in the constructor of my subclass of ModifiableObservableListBase which is constructed each time a new tab(including the corresponding TableView which is bound to the ModifiableObservableListBase ) is added to the UI.

```
 Service upDateService = new Service() {
        @Override
        protected Task createTask() {
            //when the code fails it still calls to here.
            return new Task() {

                @Override
                protected Object call() throws Exception {
                    //when the code fails it doesn't call the call() method
                    while (true) {
                        List<T> list = updateQueue.take();
                        updateLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        //now put on the FX Application Thread
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            if (list.size() > 0 && list.get(0) instanceof TableStructure) {
                                totalRowCount.set(((TableStructure) list.get(0)).getTotalDbRowCount());
                            }

                            setAll(list);

                            updateLatch.countDown();
                        });

                        try {

                            updateLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                            updateLatch = null;
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
    upDateService.start();
```

Comment: Not related to the issue, but `expr != null && expr instanceof SomeType` can simply be written as `expr instanceof SomeType` since `instanceof` yields `false` for `null`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Fabian :)

Comment: I solved this myself. Basically the Service needed to be cancelled when the Tab that owned the TableView that was bounded to the ModifiableObservableListBase (owner of the Service) was removed. Otherwise the Service seemed to be in a SCHEDULED state sometimes when the tab was readded. I'm slightly confused as to why as a new ModifiableObservableListBase (containing the Service) is created each time a tab is added so the previous Service that was initialised in ModifiableObservableListBase  should be ready for garbage collection?